# AWS ec2 - Disk uuid of volume added from a snapshot

Tags: amazon-ec2, storage, volume

When launching a new instance, suppose we add a new volume, mount it and add an `fstab` entry for auto mount on next boot. Create a snapshot of the newly added volume. Then, create an AMI out of this instance such that an additional volume is added pointing to this recently created snapshot.

This AMI will have an `fstab` entry with the UUID of the new device added e.g. `/dev/xvdb` etc.

**Question**
Suppose I launch a new instance with this AMI. Then, I have an instance with a volume made off of that snapshot. If I do a `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` then will the volume appear with a UUID different from that used to build the AMI?

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You have an EC2 instance with a volume attached and an fstab entry added.
- You have created an AMI out of it(Machine as well as the volume snapshot).
- You have launched a new instance with the created AMI, the new instance has the exact same configurations as your earlier instance(Including the volumes, meaning you have not changed even a bit when launching the new instance with AMI)

This is what I understand(Please correct me if im wrong).

If this is what you have done, then the UUID of the disk will remain same as the one which you have used to create AMI. UUID's are assigned to file systems not for disks as entities, so `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` will give the same UUID as the original.

You will also retain the fstab entries and you can simply run `sudo mount -a` to mount your volume.

You can validate this by doing `file -s /dev/your-volume-name` in the source and the clone.

Comment: When creating a new instance, I am adding volumes with the snapshots created in previously. `fstab` is not changed.

Comment: Despite that, your snapshot and the snapshot when you build an AMI are from the same source right so the volume will not appear with a different UUID from the one used to build an AMI.